# Add a class on window resize with raw javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sticky sidebar which works fine on desktop but on a tablet, the stickiness kicks in too late. i basically need the sticky class to be added somewhere nearer the top of the screen else as the screen size is smaller. what i have already is below

```
_clearStickyAd() {
    this.context.classList.remove('ad--sticky');
}

triggerStickyAd() {
    const articleBounds = this.article.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (articleBounds.top - 12 < 0) {
        this.context.classList.add('ad--sticky');
    } else {
        this._clearStickyAd();
    }

    // if ad has reached bottom of available space
    if (articleBounds.bottom - this.context.offsetHeight - this.bottomMargin < 0) {
        this.context.classList.remove('ad--sticky');
        this.adContainer.style.bottom = this.bottomMargin + mauMargin + 'px';
    } else {
        this.adContainer.style.bottom = '';
    }
}

onResize() {
    this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (this.windowWidth > deltaBreakpoint) {
        if (!this.isListening) {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.boundTriggerStickyAd);
            this.isListening = true;
        }

        if (this.windowWidth < zetaBreakpoint && this.articleMeta) {
            // at certain breakpoints article meta is below the mau ad, set property to account for this
            this.bottomMargin = this.articleMeta.offsetHeight;
        } else {
            this.bottomMargin = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (this.isListening) {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.boundTriggerStickyAd);
            this.isListening = false;
        }
    }
}

makeSticky() {
    this.bottomMargin = 0;

    // bind triggerStickyAd
    this.boundTriggerStickyAd = () => this.triggerStickyAd();

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize.bind(this));

    // call onResize to set initial values and listeners
    this.onResize();
}
```

i dont think its too complez but this code above wasnt written by me so i'm unsure how to process.

thanks

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do with that code?

Comment: Maybe you should give a link which displays similar functionality which you are trying to implement.

Comment: in a nutshell, i basically just want to know how to add a class to an element when the window is below 1024px. i'm sorry my explanation isnt the best, i dont fully understand the above code @Netham

Comment: that's what CSS media queries are for, you don't need javascript for that: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: yeah thats cool but i cant add the class with css @user2415266

Comment: If you don't understand the code, get it explained by the person who wrote it, before asking questions here.